# What is the difference between labeled data and data used for classification prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I feel very confused when attempting to handle data, especially for classification purposes. I have a dataset that initially lacked labels, so I applied a labeling method to it. Afterwards, I used the features (continuous variable) I had labeled to make predictions for labeling.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct approach for handling data in a classification task?
2. If data can be labeled using a method, why should I resort to using machine learning for classification? Are there additional benefits to using machine learning?
   [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNYgF.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I applied a labeling method"? Did you make some transformation or encoding to the target column? Or is it a column you use to make predictions?

Maybe it would be more helpful if you show what you tried so far

Comment: I use features (PM2.5, PM10, CO, SO2, O3) to evaluate label (AQI). You can seen image "Example" in question.
Then i use features to predict label (AQI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no explanation of the "labeling method" you talked about so I couldn't provide my opinion here.
2. If data can be labeled using methods, machine learning is not needed. But as you are studying right now, that is not possible to let you start with dataset will billions of complicated data, for example image data or audio data.

There is no benefit to uses machine learning on data that you can label it using methods, algorithms as it is not worth the time to train a model for it. Machine learning is generally used for complicated data such as images, example  recognize given images data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
 - Method I use to label is "https://www.kaggle.com/code/rohanrao/calculating-aqi-air-quality-index-tutorial/notebook". After that i use features to predict AQI.

Comment: Looks like there is already a complete formula to get the target values. What do you want to "predict" with ML? If you have the input values and the formula, you don't have to predict anything.

Comment: @mhenning thank you. I predict it because I want to compare result (accuracy, f1-score, marco avg) from ML(RF, SVM, KNN, ANN,...).

Comment: I think it is not a good problem to try to predict if it is trivial to solve.